# macro definition in javascript

Tags: javascript, macros

Is there a way that I can define a macro similar to C/C++ macros in Javascript?

I want to use this for debug statements:
Something like

```
#ifdef TEST__
#define MYDEBUG(##x) debug(__FILE__,x)
#else
#define debug
#endif
```

Not necessarily similar, but I want to acheieve that functionality. Is there a way I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: In what way would using something akin to a macro here be different than just using inline programming logic you store in a function and call at will?

Comment: is different because it's evaluated at compile time, not at runtime.

Comment: Macro automatically picks up the __FILE__, __FUNCTION__ (if compiler allows) and __LINE__ automatically.. this makes the code look cleaner as we are not cluttering it with this information with every function call

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I simulate macros in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193536/how-can-i-simulate-macros-in-javascript)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
var de = false; // true when debugging
function bug( msg ){ ... display msg ... }
```

Usage:

```
de&&bug( "hello world")
```

When "de" is false (production mode), the overhead is minimal.

Comment: This is very clever.  The problem with programmatic solutions is that if the debug function is argument-heavy, you have to pay for computing and passing the arguments to the function body, even if the function is empty.  This trick avoids that problem -- in production code the actual debug function is never called.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has no macros since there is no compiler. You could use `console.log` and write a regex to strip those statements when deploying.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this in JavaScript. You could have a global variable like

```
var isDebugging = false;
```

Then when writing code, just check if the variable is true. Obviously this will create some unwanted overhead with file size, and a very slight performance loss. But other than specifying your own format, and running the code though a tool to strip debugging code out before you upload.

Something like

```
var foo = function() {
   <!-- document.write( "blah" ); -->
};
```

For a release build, you would remove everything inside the  tags, inclusive. And for a debug build you could just remove the tags, but keep the code. Something like this could be performed with an Ant build script or similar.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still interested:

https://github.com/dcodeIO/Preprocessor.js

> A JavaScript source file preprocessor in pure JavaScript, e.g. to build different versions of a library.

Examples:

```js
// #ifdef FULL
console.log("Including extension");
// #include "path/to/extension.js"
// #else
console.log("Not including extension");
// #endif

// #if 1==2
console.log("1==2");
// #elif 2==2
console.log("2==2");
// #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

While is true that there is no compile time as @sapht said, you can pre-process your files if you want. Typically I use an ant script to combine many Javascript files together and add build information.

From a google search I see there is a Javascript preprocessor that you may find interesting: http://www.bramstein.com/projects/preprocess/

Answer (score 0):

With *Builder* – https://github.com/electricimp/Builder, you can do like:

```
@macro MYDEBUG(x)
  debug(@{__FILE__}, @{x});
@end

...

@{MYDEBUG(100500)}
```

Also supports for includes directly from GitHub.