# Macro in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, macros

In javascript, if a function creates a function and then returns it, the returned function's scope is relative to where it was created.

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a block of code stored in a variable which acts almost like preprocessor macros in C/C++, but with the difference being it can be treated like a variable? Where, essentially, you create this macro, assign it to a variable, and wherever the macro is executed, the scope of the code is always relative to where it was executed.

An example (not real code):

```
macro someMacro {
    this.i++

    a++
}

function someFunc() {
    this.i = 0;

    var a = 0;

    console.log(this.i, a) // 0, 0

    someMacro();

    console.log(this.i, a) // 1, 1
}
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980708/macro-definition-in-javascript) question, but that's not quite what I want.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `.bind()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: For `a` there is imho no way except doing some _dirty_ `eval`  stuff. But I think the question is why you would like to do that. If someone reads your code no one would expect that `someMacro()`  could/would change `a`, so this would be bad practice anyway.

Comment: @Lauromine, No, I know how to use .bind, I use it all of the time. I thought it was a bit of a longshot, this question. I've been using JavaScript for about 6 years now, I did think it was unlikely that I would have missed a feature such as the one I described in my question.

Comment: @t.niese, I believe you are correct. I think this could be a handy feature if ever standardised in the spec, but of course it's not a requirement to have this feature. I was just curious to know if I'd somehow overlooked such a capability of JavaScript over the years.

Comment: Perhaps you want [`sweetjs`](http://sweetjs.org/) which provides macros as a transcompiler.

Comment: I had come across sweetjs during my initial research before asking the question, but I'd prefer not to use a library.