# JavaScript Macro Recorder

Tags: javascript, jquery, macros

I am building a web application which I would like to contain a macro recorder, like the one demonstrated here: http://blog.metawrap.com/2007/06/22/javascript-macro-recorder/

The problem with this macro recorder is that isn't maintained any longer, and appears to break in newer browsers (or, at least in Chrome). Are there any JavaScript/jQuery based macro recorders that you can recommend.

**Note:** I am not referring to anything related to "Lisp-style" macros that are referenced in  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193536/how-can-i-simulate-macros-in-javascript). I mean an actual macro recorder that will capture and record mouse and keyboard events.

Comment: Have you tested this macro recorder in any browser besides Chrome? I've only tested it in Chrome, and it doesn't work in Chrome at all.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Great find! No, I know the link I provided doesn't work at all in Chrome. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not yet found any libraries for macro recording, but it may be possible to record macros by [capturing keyboard and mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695913/capture-all-the-events-javascript?lq=1) or [listening for events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321672/listen-for-all-events-in-javascript) on a page. I found several JavaScript libraries for recording keyboard and mouse actions, so they may be useful for macro recording:

- [evtrack](https://github.com/luileito/evtrack) is a library for event-tracking, including keyboard and mouse-tracking.
- [musjs](https://github.com/ineventapp/musjs) tracks mouse movements.

It might even be possible to "play back" recorded macros by [simulating clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript) and [key presses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically) on a page. To record a macro on more than one browser tab, it might be necessary to [send messages between the tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows).

Answer (score 2):

The following opensource records mouse movements:
https://github.com/danielwix/wix-client-recorder

It is an entirely client-side project.