# is there any way to instrument javascript event handler firing using javascript?

Tags: javascript

is there any universal way to instrument javascript event handler firing using javascript? 
for example, I want to do something before the event handler firing, so when to fire an event, I would like to execute my code first then the event handler code.

The problem is that there are multiple ways to register event handlers, I would like to handle all of them: html, javascript

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489433/monitor-all-javascript-events-in-the-browser-console

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture all the events (javascript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695913/capture-all-the-events-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not.

You can hook `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`, which would allow you to intercept both the registration and invocation of event listeners by JS code. However, this will not capture event listeners set in ways such as `elt.onclick`. Nor of course will it catch listeners set up via the old IE `attachEvent` API. Most importantly, it will not help with you that events that are generated and listened for internally, such as a mouse click on a check box.

You might be tempted to hook `createEvent` and `dispatchEvent` in similar fashion, but that will capture only events that are explicitly created or dispatched in the JS code.