# Capturing the events through some code of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

Is there anyway to capture all the events in a page dynamically through JavaScript / jQuery code.
For example, if I click on a button I should know that `onclick` of a button happened through some code.

Please help me in  capturing all the events dynamically. I know this can be done using `monitorEvents` in Chrome and Firefox, but I want to capture the events through some code.

Comment: This is quite vague. Yes, you can capture events like clicks, mouse over, mouse position,etc. Provide an example of the HTML you are trying to capture events in

Comment: @Cory, he probably wants to add a single callback to all events.

Comment: @Srinivas have you explored the possibility of catching event on the top node when it's bubbling down ? As long as nodes are proper children (not position fixed or absolute kind) you'll be able to know that even was invoked.

Comment: @Cory I am not sure how to capture all the events.

Comment: I believe what you want is: `document.addEventListener('click', delegator, false);`
`document.addEventListener('touch', delegator, false);`
`document.addEventListener('mouseover', delegator, false);` etc... Then everything that happens in the document is listened to.

Comment: Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695913/capture-all-the-events-javascript. Might help you.