# Redirect all events from one object to another

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to write a small game engine for the canvas in vanilla javascript, in my current mental model of how it would work, the user would instantiate a Scene class that would contain all objects to be rendered as well as their behavior. There would only be one active scene at a time per canvas, so that scenes that are not currently loaded are inactive. As such, I'd like to be able to redirect all events that are dispatched to the canvas to the currently active scene. It would look something like this:

```
canvas.addEventListener(/* all */, (e) => activeScene.dispatchEvent(e));
```

but obviously this does not work.

There is an interesting answer to a similar question here: [Listen for all events in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321672/listen-for-all-events-in-javascript)

that goes something along the lines of iterating over all window properties and registering an event listener for all properties that start with "on".

Problem is, this won't catch custom events, and I'd like to enable the user to interact with their scenes using custom events dispatched from other places (for example a button above the canvas to reset the current level could send a 'reset' event).

The alternatives would be:

1. the user calls a custom function on the canvas that then calls the appropriate function on the currently active scene
2. The user dispatches a custom event as I was thinking but also has to add an event listener for that event type and redirect the event to the active scene manually (or I provide a function to register the custom event and redirect events of this type to the active scene)

In all those cases it's a 2 step process for the user. I guess registering all custom events once at the start of the program wouldn't be that bad but I was wondering if there existed a more elegant solution.

Comment: Each scene could have its own canvas. Show the active scene's canvas, hide all others.

Comment: @ChrisG I fail to understand how that would address my problem in any capacity. It would just shift the problem, I'd have to have a global object that keeps track of the active canvas instead of the active scene (which are now synonyms) and dispatches events it receives to that canvas. Or dispatch the event to all canvases and they'd have to check whether they're active before handling the event.

Comment: It's a suggestion about an alternative approach, that's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer. Let me try something and get back to you.

Comment: Can you add example code to your question that shows how an engine user would set up, say, two scenes? Including the user adding event listeners to them? What I mean is, pretend you already have a perfect solution implemented. How would the user's code look like in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after some tinkering here is the solution I came up with:

I redirect all standard events using eventListeners with this code

```
for(let key in myObj){
    if(key.startsWith('on')) {
       myObj.addEventListener(key.slice(2), (e) => {otherObj.dispatchEvent(e)});
    }
}
```

and I overwrite the default `dispatchEvent()` method so that all manually fired events are redirected regardless of their type:

```
myObj.dispatchEvent = (e) => {otherObj.dispatchEvent(e)};
```

Unfortunately the first part is necessary because standard events are not fired through the `dispatchEvent()` method. In theory this should redirect all events fired on the object (which in my case would be the canvas) to the other (the active scene).