# Is there a way to view the contents of a predefined function like alert()?

Tags: javascript, function

I want to make a custom alert, but I read that the alert cannot be customized, so I want to make a new function I can edit.

This is for a html webpage I am making. I have searched Stack Overflow and Google for the answer.

```
alert("This is a normal alert.");
function specialAlert() {
//How do I get this?
}
```

I expected the `alert()` to be editable, but it isn’t.

Comment: `alert()` is built-in and I think it can't be customized

Comment: Will give you a run down on what you need to do to create the custom alert. If you are wanting to make a custom alert, first create it in html and css and use css to position it on the page where you want it. add a class called something like displayNone to the html element, and the style for that class will be display: none; Use javascript to remove this class when there is a click event and it will display your alert. Use keyframes to add a nice animation to it.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible. The function is composed of native code:

```js
console.log(window.alert.toString());
```

From an answer on a [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655690/detecting-when-a-variable-changes-in-javascript/55680733#55680733):

> [Native code] means that it's not an ordinary Javascript function. Functions composed of native code are always functions provided by the browser (or whatever environment the code is running in); they often cannot be emulated by any Javascript functions you write yourself. For example, *only* the [`window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) object can perform history actions like `history.back()`; if `window.history` gets overwritten, and you don't have a saved reference to it or any other `history` objects, there's no way to write your own function that can do `history.back()`, because `.back()` invokes *privileged native code* that requires an interface between the visible Javascript and the browser engine.

Many functions made from native code are not implementable in plain Javascript, including `alert`, because it uses *privileged browser-provided functions*. Unless all you want to do is *alter* the text that gets displayed in the alert box (or if the alert appears at all), perhaps by monkeypatching `window.alert`, no further customization is possible.

That said, it's good to avoid `alert` anyway in most cases, because it's pretty user-unfriendly. Better to construct a proper modal that doesn't block.

Answer (score 1):

Lucky for you, I created a quick alert example for you :P

Have a bit of a look at the code and you will get the idea. Things to take away are 1. how to use position: absolute 2. how to add and remove a class from an html element and 3. click events. Enjoy

```js
const alertButton = document.querySelector('.showAlert');
const customAlert = document.querySelector('.alert');
const closeAlert = document.querySelector('.closeAlert');
var tof = false;
alertButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if(!tof) {
    customAlert.classList.remove("displayNone");
    tof = !tof;
  } else {
    customAlert.classList.add("displayNone");
    tof = !tof;
  }
});

closeAlert.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  tof = false;
  customAlert.classList.add("displayNone");
});
```

```css
.alert{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(50, 166, 243);
  color: white;
}

.alertContent {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.closeAlert {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.closeAlert:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.displayNone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert displayNone">
  <div class="alertContent"> This is an alert which is cool</div>
  <div class="closeAlert">X</div>
</div>

<button class="showAlert">Show Alert</button>
```

code pen here: https://codepen.io/mitchell-boland/pen/arBNBw

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are looking for a better styling of the generic-looking pop-up alert window.

With this, I recommend trying [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert2.github.io/).

According to the doc, it is a beautiful, responsive and customizable replacement for the default pop-up boxes of browsers.

Click on the link and play with the demo.

Answer (score -1):

How about using bootstrap modal to display the message instead? [Check it here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)