# Can We Observe changes in a variable's Value with - MyVar.addEventListener("change" , function(){});?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I got some results on google - Object.observe() (depreciated)..

My Possible Code:

```
// Vanilla JavaScript

var MyVar = "hi";

MyVar.addEventListener("change" , function (){}); //Should the code inside the function work on the value of variable changes.??


MyVar = "bye";
```

Or I Should Use:

```
function myfunction (){

var OldMyVar = "Hi";
var MyVar = "Hi";

MyVar = "Bye";

if(MyVar !== OldMyVar){

alert("My Var Has Changed");
OldMyVar = MyVar;

}

}

setInterval(myfunction,100);
```

So Should I Use This??

Comment: On objects you can use getter/setter to do this. On variables, no. Also refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680733/3783478)

Comment: Something like observables or channels may help. RxJS for example. Also, it's "deprecated," not "depreciated."

Comment: I want to use vanilla js