# is there a javascript "any value" selector?

Tags: javascript

i'm making a javascript mod (name: xi). one of the first things im making in xi is `is_true`, an event type. here is how it is used:

```js
event(is_true(insert boolean), function(){
});
```

function:

```js
if (eventType == is_true(// "any" selector)) {
}
```

i need an "[any value]" selector, kinda like the one in css except it returns any value.

## I cannot understand this stuff

well, say that the css selector `*` existed in javascript and it behaved like this:

```js
typeof * // Returns "Any"
```

and if `List()` would be a thing, `List(*)` could return:

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, ... Infinity, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", ... true, false, ...]
```

so have you found something similar to it?
`<hr>`
time for a q&a!!!

question number one:
when will is true return false
is_true kills 99.99% boolean (is_true is not boolean but it involves something like wait until [boolean here])
but anyways,

```
// if is_true() was a boolean
is_true(not(true)) // javascript ! is xi "not"
// D U H .
```

or

```
is_true(false)
```

### *D U H*

## WAIT NEVER MIND

there is a solution

```
var Any;
```

and if you need multiple "any"'s, u just gotta
do

```
Any
Any_ii
Any_iii
...
```

and

```
// kills 99.99% boolean
event
```

Comment: Under what conditions will `is_true` return false? With which arguments?

Comment: If you want to return true for anything, just return true...

Comment: Javascript considers 0, undefined, null, false, "", and NaN to be falsey. Everything else is truthy. This means that for any value of a variable named ointments, `if (ointments)` is valid. It will be false for the six listed values and true for anything else. If you want it to be true for the top six values as well, do as @Idos sad and just return true.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321672/listen-for-all-events-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

`is_true` feels like a code smell, and a bad idea.

After all, if something is true... you don't need to wrap it in a function to check this. If the goal of `is_true` is to check is something is, well, not false... then these two should be the same:

```
if (is_true(something))
if (something)
```

When you describe 'any value', including `false`, then `is_true()` is kind of a bad name. You don't want `is_true()` to return `true` when you call it with `is_true(false)` because that just gets extremely confusing.

When a variable exists, it has a value. Maybe the only type of value that you could possibly describe as 'the absence of a value' is the `undefined` keyword. In that case you are still better off making this explicit by letting your users do:

```
if (x !== undefined)
```

instead of something like:

```
if (is_defined(x))
```

However, my sense is that you really just need

```
if (x)
```

and no extra functions

Comment: You might want to note that if the variable or argument has not been declared you would have to test like `if(typeof x !== 'undefined')` or the Browser will throw an Error. If you were testing for an undeclared property on an existing Object, then that first type of undefined test is fine. Just a comment.

Comment: is_true() is not a boolean, it is event type

Comment: also i needed the any value thingy for the script that defined ```event()```

Comment: @anova01 nothing you're saying really makes sense, I'm sorry. Maybe your naming needs to be better?

Comment: Your edits also... impossible to understand.

Comment: sorry i'm a weirdscratch'r :/