# JS: how to get a list of all available JS events (and subscribe to them) to record them?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the list of all available JS events (like keypress, keyup, click, touchstart, scroll..)

My goal is to record ALL interactions an user have done in a webpage and play it back.
(like filling forms, button clicks, scrolls)

1. is it possible to list all these events (and subscribe to all these events) in JS ?
2. maybe something similar was already done ? (I could find just some keys or mouse recording, but not ALL events)

Comment: have a look in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321672/listen-for-all-events-in-javascript
it might be what you are searching for.

Comment: There is no builtin list available, except maybe from the property names on an element. You're probably better off looking into the HTML specs, or [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events), for such a list, as you'll want to know how to process these events anyway - some of them might require special handling for replaying.

Comment: yes: exactly what I was looking for!