# How to call a function when any JavaScript event occurs?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a requirement to check if the user is active or inactive in UI5. So I need to call a function when there is some kind of user events. I have done it as follows. But is there a better way without listing the events as below?

```
**

jQuery(document).on("blur focus click dblclick mousedown mouseup mouseover mouseout etc", function(oEvent) {
    //call some function
    }
```

**

Comment: You could take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5848702/9636400 although you might be better of doing what you're already doing.

Comment: Couldn't you just have a check to see if the user is logged in or not? Capturing every event seems like overkill, and (imo) weirdly intrusive.

Comment: What is the app supposed to do if the user is inactive in UI5?

Comment: Does your app need to support Safari users as well?

Answer (score 1):

You do not to listen to all those events. These are enough.

```
$(document).on("scroll mouseover mouseup focus blur", (event) => {
  console.log("User interaction", event.originalEvent)
})
```

You also need to listen to these events:

```
  keydown
  resize
  auxclick
```

---

```
   $(document).on("scroll mouseover mouseup focus blur keydown auxclick", (event) => {
      console.log("User interaction", event.originalEvent)
    })

   $(window).on("resize", (event) => {
      console.log("User interaction", event.originalEvent)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to prove a negative, but no, I'm pretty sure there's no "catch all" event handler mechanism. If there were, it would be likely mentioned in the [MDN documentation for `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and/or [the specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-eventtarget-addeventlistener%E2%91%A2).

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do so.

By doing that, your code would be flooded with an amount of events really hard to manage, and performances (and responsiveness) would be very low.

However, this question has been more or less answered recently. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68426949/18860952 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/48388878/18860952