# Get triggered events from all elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

To give a bit of context, I am conducting a research focused on digital marketing and user experience. To enable the research, it is essential that I am able to get event logs from every component in an UI so I am, then, able to create datasets of usability pattern.

To do so in a web interface, e.g. using JavaScript, that's very simple.

```
window.addEventListener("someEvent", (e) => {//do something with the data});
```

The `e` element gives me everything I need, and If I want to listen to all window events, I can [run a for loop through the window object events and add an event listener to each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321672/listen-for-all-events-in-javascript). My issue is with **mobile development**. For cross application reasons, am I am using React Native to try to create the same effect as `window.addEventListener` to mobile apps.

This is my first time using React Native. After a bit of searching, I am now aware that React Native does not have a window object (at least not as we understand window in JavaScript) and that the interface is translated to the platform native components, so `document.getElementBy...` would't work either.

What I though of was `refs`. I would only need to add a reference to the top component `App`. So what I have working so far:

```
export default function App() {
  const viewRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    //I can use ref here to iterate through all events of View and
    //bind event listeners to it
  }, [viewRef]);

  return (
    <View
      ref={viewRef}
      style={styles.container}
      onTouchEnd={(e) => {
        console.log(e.target);
      }}
    >
      <DummyComponent />
    </View>
  );
}
```

`onTouchEnd` event is bind to the top-layer component, so I can get everything that is a child of it. In that useEffect, I can do the same thing I would with JavaScript's window.

So I guess this is one way to do it. However, in my research I would like to enable any React Native app to begin logging events seamlessly. The state of the art would be creating a dependency that would being logging everything simply by installing it. That said, **how can I iterate a React Native application to find Views and bind their events, without need to add ANYTHING to the actual component?**

In JavaScript it would be something like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("View").map((view) => {//bind view events});
```

Comment: `To enable the research, it is essential that I am able to get event logs from every component in an UI`. There are tools for this that will do a better job than you could come up with by rolling your own. https://segment.com/docs/connections/sources/catalog/libraries/mobile/react-native/ or https://www.npmjs.com/package/@heap/react-native-heap

Comment: Thanks for the tips. However, I would still like to know how I can accomplish this.

Comment: This probably isn't like the best answer, but one way would be to change the `defaultProps` of the component before rendering. I did a similar thing to set the default `fontSize` and `fontFamily` for every `Text` component, you could do the same for `onTouchEnd` for every `View` component for example

Comment: Without completely understanding your endgoal (rejecting 3rd party tools), your "javascript" solution would also fail with react, as the dom could easily change and your events would become orphants.

Comment: @LuísMestre that seems promising. How so? Can you give me a simple dummy snippet?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure if this can help, but you can change the defaultProps of a component on start of your application.

So using your code as example you could do something like this:

```js
const listener = e => {
  console.log(e);
}

View.defaultProps = {
  ...View.defaultProps, // maintains original default props
  onTouchEnd: listener
};
```

Basically this way you can have a global listener for each View component

Comment: Thanks, Luís! Do you have any insights in how I could get all the View elements of the current component? Kind of a document.getElementByTagName("View")?

Comment: Borrowing this answer from another stackoverflow question:

`window` and `document` are part of the web standard, not JavaScript (ECMA standard) itself. `document` is part of the DOM standard. React Native, although indeed runs on JavaScript for controlling the render, does not have a standards-compliant DOM implementation. So many (if not most) web-based (or DOM-based) React examples are not applicable to React Native, especially those doing DOM-manipulation.