# React Native - Bind function to View event using ref inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I bind a function to handle a `View` component event using it's reference inside an `useEffect` in React Native? I tried a few things (see below code) and they all return `viewRef.current.something is undefined`. I logged the entire `current` object and looked through it extensively and found nothing.

```
export default function App() {
  const viewRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (viewRef && viewRef.current) {
      //viewRef.current.addEventListener is undefiend
      viewRef.current.addEventListener("onTouchEnd", (e) => {
        //do something
      });
      //viewRef.current.onTouchEnd is undefiend
      viewRef.current.onTouchEnd((e) =>{
        //do something
      })
    }
  }, [viewRef]);

  return (
    <View ref={viewRef} style={styles.container}>
      <DummyComponent />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: You don't use refs for this: `<View onTouchEnd={() => { your function }}/>`. https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.67/gesture-responder-system

Comment: I cannot specify it directly. I now that setting it like that will work, but I need to specify it after the render and outside the JSX.

Comment: I need at least 15 characters to ask this - why?

Comment: @Adam https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73520897/get-triggered-events-from-all-elements