# Touchscreen get browser click or mouse event type

Tags: javascript, jquery, touchscreen

We have an Elo touchscreen that has multi touch.  This can be probably for most touch screens as well, but we are trying to capture the "event type" on the body when a user touches the screen so we can trigger a timeout event. Right now we are using jQuery just for ease.

```
$('body').on("click mouseover mousedown touchstart touchend mouseup", function(e){
   console.log("trigger type" + e.type);  
 });
```

Is there a way with Javascript (or jQuery) to get the touch type without first defining the events we want to watch for?
Instead of having to define and watching, setting a case statement, etc for "click", "mousedown", etc.
Is there a way to just get the event type?

My assumption is probably not, but since it is a proprietary touchscreen manufacturer, knowing the type from the DOM would be helpful.  We are using Chrome/Chromium for a web app interactive for this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're going for, but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68461531/4935162) will nudge you in... a direction? What do you you mean `just get the event type`?

Comment: @Yarin_007, I think we will just stick with our solution for now.  Thank you for the link. 
After some thought, there are probably so many events running that getting the "event type" would be a bit much.  When I say "Event Type", I am referring to the interaction type (touchend, touchstart, click, mousedown, mouseup,etc.)  that way we can track down and target what the browser and the touchscreen is registering.

Comment: I will be closing this question since even doing some of my own research, this is not quite possible.