# Javascript alias for "Function" keyword

Tags: javascript, function, alias, keyword

Ahoi community,

Is there a possibility to define an alias for the javascript keyword "Function"?

```
var f = Function; // define Function alias

var foobar = f() // write 'f' as replacement for 'function'
{        
    console.log("foobar") 
};

foobar();
```

Comment: You can't create aliases for keywords, though [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) is not a keyword, it's the name of a function.

Comment: It's definitely not, but why do you need this?

Comment: Its just like asking, I want to create an alias for `var`. `function` is a javascript reserved keyword.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy `function` != `Function`

Comment: @DaveNewton `Function` can be saved as a reference somewhere. But by looking at OP's approach, I suspect his aim was just creating an alias for `function` keyword. :)

Comment: `constructor.constructor("return 123*456")()` surprises many devs...

Comment: There are [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Thanks Xufox. Arrow functions are close to what I was looking for.

Comment: As for why this would be useful, it would allow greater compression by JS minifiers, as well as more readable code with lots of closures or anonymous functions. Like `var a = b(fn(){});` versus `var a = b(function(){});`. Most JS libraries use aliases, like the common `$ = function(id){return document.getElementById(id);}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions is what I was looking for (thx Xufox).

It's useful to minify your JS (thx Beejor).

To me it is also better readable and faster to code :)

So the snippet in the original question would look like:

```
var foobar = () => console.log("foobar"); 

foobar();
```

Comment: Is it more readable for the other developer that you work with?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot, but you can have anonymous functions, named functions and/or function expressions.

For example,

```
//named function
function Test( param1, param2) { /* code goes here */}

//function expression
var foo = function (param1, param2) { /* code goes here */}
foo('test1','test2')

//anonymous function
function (param1, param2) { /* this is one is problematic */}
```

I recommend you go through a javascript tutorial basics.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is more similar to this

[How can I simulate macros in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193536/how-can-i-simulate-macros-in-javascript)

Then take a look at http://sweetjs.org/ doc.